# asciidoc: Is there a way to get around the problem of lines beginning with [colour] attributes ending with ] not displaying in asciidoc?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

My target asciidoc text is this:

`[red]#Some prompt[x]# Make sure the option is [checked]`

But it won't display in asciidoc

On further investigation, I found that any line beginning with a [colour] in square brackets, and ending in a right-bracket is similarly not displayed.

Now, in this case, I've got around the problem by putting the whole prompt section in bold, like this:

`*[red]#Some prompt[x]#* Make sure the option is [checked]`

but this is not ideal. Adding a period after the final close bracket `\]` also AVOIDS the problem - but in my use case I didn't like it.

I'd like to know if there is a better way.  So far I've tried:

1. Escaping the leading open bracket `\[`
2. Escaping the final close bracket `\]`
3. Removing the `[x]` in the middle, thinging the additional brackets in the middle may influence the outcome

but none of these has worked.

So my question is:

*Is there a way to get around the problem of lines beginning with [colour] attributes ending with ] not displaying in asciidoc?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that a line which begins with an opening bracket and ends with a closing bracket is being interpreted as a block attribute line.

There are a number of ways you can mitigate this.

---

Use a [character replacement attribute](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/character-replacement-ref/). There are many built-in attributes, or you can easily [define your own](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/custom-attributes/).

For example:

```
[.red]#Some prompt[x]# Make sure the option is [checked{endsb}
```

---

Use one of the [inline pass-through](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/pass/pass-macro/) syntaxes, for example `++`:

```
[.red]#Some prompt[x]# Make sure the option is [checked++]++
```

---

Prevent the first opening bracket from being the first character of the line. Also, uses a built-in attribute, and the markup needs to be changed to [unconstrained](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/text/troubleshoot-unconstrained-formatting/).

For example:

```
{empty}[.red]##Some prompt[x]## Make sure the option is [checked]
```

Comment: Wow. Not one answer but three. Thanks so much for your comprehensive and cross-referenced answer which I'm sure will be of benefit to others.